# Selector for an element with certain class, if it is the one & only child of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply certain CSS to an element(with a certain class) if it is the **one & only child within its parent**. I can easily do this using jQuery but I'm looking for a pure CSS solution(that works across all major browsers). How do write selector expression for such elements ?

**E.g. scenario:**

```
<div> 
   <span class='a1'/>
</div>

<div> 
   <a>random text</a>
   <span class='a1'/>
</div>
```

I would like the first `div` contained `.a1` element to be selected as it is the only element within its parent.

Comment: Another similar question I posted today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108581/selector-for-an-element-with-certain-class-if-it-is-the-one-only-visible-ch

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Cross browser compatibility,

```
.a1:first-child:last-child {
     color :red;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TdN52/)

Comment: `first-child` is  supported by many old browsers but I think `last-child` browser compatiblity is same as `only-child`'s , Isn't it ? So this would work the same as if using `only-child` ?

Comment: See 1.) http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3aonly-child & 2.) http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Alast-child

Comment: @user01 Yes, It belongs to the css3 property list.

Comment: so what's recommended your original answer or using `only-child` ?

Comment: @user01 It depends on what is more understandable to you, because both are having only possibilities to work under latest browsers. IE < 9 definitely not.

Comment: @user01 If you consider using Jquery, you don't need to worry about backward compatibility problems. I am suggesting this because you were talking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.a1:only-child` see  [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnQgL/). Of course, it depends on what you consider "major browsers" as to whether it is [supported or not](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3aonly-child) (it is a CSS3 property).

Comment: Thanks Scott! Do you think Rajaprabhu's solution would work for more browsers. Acc. to the page you linked to, I saw that `first-child` is supported by many old browsers but I think `last-child`'s browser compatiblity is same as `only-child`'s , So would  Rajaprabhu's solution work any better(meaning older browsers compatilbility like <IE8) than if using `only-child` ?

Comment: another thing, not related to the original question, but if you could also suggest a way to write *Selector for an element with certain class, if it is the one & only **visible child** of its parent*(meaning there could be more elments but if they are hidden then consider visible child to be only child )

Comment: @user01: With `last-child` having same support as `only-child`, probably no better. There is no way in CSS to detect `visibility` or `display` of an element. That is only possible via javascript.