# Selector for an element with certain class, if it is the one & only "visible" child of its parent?

Tags: html, css

Just today I asked

> [Selector for an element with certain class, if it is the one & only child of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106929/selector-for-an-element-with-certain-class-if-it-is-the-one-only-child-of-its)

but what about if we need to select elements with a class , if it is the one & only "**visible**" child of its parent?  I know it can be easily done using jQuery but I'm looking for a pure CSS solution(that works across all major browsers). Can I  write CSS selector expression for such elements ?

Comment: How are you hiding the elements that you want avoid styling?

Comment: @DavidThomas: using `display:none`

Comment: yeah but that may be directly on the element or via a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to determine if an object is "visible" with CSS, so it's not possible. Note that jQuery is also only capable of determining if an object is "visible" *for a certain definition of "visible"*.

Here's an [example where it fails](http://jsfiddle.net/k47mc/):

```
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: -100px">Am I visible?</div>
</body>
```

Here is [another](http://jsfiddle.net/6q3AW/). Heck, even `visibility: hidden` [is considered visible](http://jsfiddle.net/UxQuz/). There are lots of creative ways to make something "not visible" to a human, so that term needs a rigorous definition before we are able to start talking tech.

Comment: *visibile* for my case would mean if the element is not `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you, we select in css dude, its just example how to select

```
   div > .child:not( [style*='visibility:hidden'] ) {
   border-top:    1px solid #cccccc;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;

 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k47mc/3/)

another

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k47mc/2/)

Comment: The flaw, which you fail to mention, is that you have to hide the element using inline styles, rather than a stylesheet; which means two separate CSS approaches have to be followed and maintained.

Comment: its just knowledge based.

Comment: I have no idea of that's a response, or a non-sequitur. But yes, maybe; though do you think the OP is mindful of the limitations, given the question? Also, in what way does this meet the "if, and only if" part if the requirement; your approach styles the elements that are not hidden (for a given value of 'hidden'), but in bio way limits the selection to 'only one.'